# Print certain section of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have searched a fair bit to try and find a result that will let me print just one section of a page.

Everyone is saying to do this:

### Add to HTML head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

### print.css

```
body * { display: none; }
.printable { display: block; }
```

### Javascript

```
window.print();
```

But I cannot get this to work, It loads the print window, but doesn't actually display anything.

http://pmf.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/set_times

Here is my page which has a print link on the right hand side.

Kind regards, 
Shannon

Comment: use @print media queries, btw nice website :)

Comment: I don't see print.css nor printable on your website. Have you added them already?

Comment: Thankyou @Mr.Alien! That's exactly what I'm using, but I still can't get the results I'm needing :(

Comment: @suke I'm using media print queries in the main.css :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `body *` selector is more specific than `.printable`, so it's overriding it. Use something like this in your `print.css` file instead:

```
* {
    display: none;
}
body .printable {
    display: block;
}
```